# update-ca-certificates command not found despite ca-certificates being installed

Tags: linux, certificate, gnu, cacerts

I've installed ca-certificates package by `sudo yum install ca-certificates` command, but I get an error when trying to run `sudo update-ca-certificates` command, becuase it can not be found. What can be the problem? I tried looking for the package (in case if it was problem with PATH), but I didn't manage to find it on the machine.

Comment: Whis linux distribution and version are you using? I faced a similar problem but solved it by finding the `update-ca-certificates` command with `sudo find /usr/ -name 'update-ca-certificates'`

Answer (score 9):

For other folks running into similar problems, this info may be helpful.

[Here](https://github.com/millermatt/osca) is a GitHub repo (mine) that documents the different commands used to update CA certs on various operating systems.

From that repo:

| System | Copy new certs here | Command to trust new certs | Install cert management tool |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alpine | `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/` | `update-ca-certificates` | `apk add ca-certificates` |
| Amazon Linux | `/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/` | `update-ca-trust extract` | `yum install ca-certificates` |
| Arch | `/etc/ca-certificates/trust-source/anchors/` | `trust extract-compat` | `pacman -Sy ca-certificates-utils` |
| CentOS | `/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/` | `update-ca-trust extract` | `yum install ca-certificates` |
| CoreOS | `/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/` | `update-ca-certificates` | Built into the system |
| Debian | `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/` | `update-ca-certificates` | `apt-get install -y ca-certificates` |
| Fedora | `/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/` | `update-ca-trust extract` | `dnf install ca-certificates` |
| MacOS | `/Library/Keychains/System.keychain` | `security add-trusted-cert -d -r trustRoot -k /Library/Keychains/System.keychain <path_to_cert>` | Built into the system |
| RedHat | `/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/` | `update-ca-trust extract` | `yum install ca-certificates` |
| SUSE | `/etc/pki/trust/anchors/` | `update-ca-certificates` | `zypper install ca-certificates` |
| Ubuntu | `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/` | `update-ca-certificates` | `apt-get install -y ca-certificates` |
| Windows | `C:\Windows\System32\certsrv\CertEnroll\` | `certutil -addstore -f "Root" <path_to_cert>` | Built into the system |

The repo also has a Linux bash script that will detect the current distribution and call the appropriate commands to install the cert utility (if necessary) and update certs.

Comment: This was really helpful matrix!

Answer (score 6):

Not all Linux versions use `update-ca-certificates` -- I ran into a similar problem when trying to run `update-ca-certificates` on Fedora, and found that the equivalent command on Fedora is called `update-ca-trust` instead. Here's [Fedora's documentation](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/using-shared-system-certificates/#_adding_new_certificates) on how to add a new certificate:

> you can simply copy the certificate file in the PEM or DER file format to the /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/ directory, followed by running the update-ca-trust command, for example:
>
> ```
> cp ~/certificate-trust-examples/Cert-trust-test-ca.pem /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/
>
> update-ca-trust
> ```

You can find out what specific distribution and version of Linux you're on by running `cat /etc/os-release`. From there you can look up your OS' documentation on how to add a certificate authority on your OS.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/go-toolset
COPY --from=docker.io/golang:latest /usr/sbin/update-ca-certificates /usr/sbin/update-ca-certificates
COPY local-ca.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
RUN set -x && cd /usr/local/share/ca-certificates && update-ca-certificates
```

Cheers!